# How do I block HTML5 video element from registering touch through a layer on iPhone or iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, touch, touch-event, html5-video

I discovered this unusual and somewhat annoying behavior when starting a new HTML5 video player project from scratch.

I have a very basic webpage with the following tags:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <video id="vid" src="someVideo.mp4" width="960" height="540"></video>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 960px; height: 540px; background-color: red;"></div>
</div>
```

It appears as expected - the VIDEO element is hidden behind the big red rectangle that has the same exact dimensions.

Against my expectations, however, I can touch the center area of the red rectangle around where that play "overlay" that appears at the center of every HTML5 video on the iPhone or iPod Touch is located to cause the VIDEO element to start playing as if I touched the VIDEO element itself.

Is there some way to block this behavior? It doesn't occur on the iPad or on the desktop, but by the same token the overlay also doesn't appear on these platforms with a raw VIDEO tag on the page.

**UPDATE:** It seems to go so far as to block the touch event from anything positioned directly over it. If I try to attach an event listener to the absolutely positioned red DIV the associated event handler won't execute. This is really quite annoying.

**UPDATE:** @Matt H - This is a "web app" running in iOS's Safari. Through vigorous testing I have concluded that on an iPhone or iPod Touch the area in which a VIDEO element "resides" on the physical page is essentially reserved for that element as far as events are concerned so long as it's actually visible. The problem of course is that if the VIDEO element is not displayed then you can't chain a play method call from a touch on the overlay element. This sucks, but I assume it's part of Apple's efforts to prevent malicious coders from "tricking" users into playing VIDEO much like the "no autoplay" rule.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try handling and canceling the touch event?

```
<body ontouchstart='return HandleTouch(event)'>
function HandleTouch(ev) {ev.preventDefault(); }
```

I don't know for certain if that'll work, though.

Comment: If it works for your needs, I would just set the video tag to display:none; then show and play it when you need it... assuming the video element would indeed be hidden!

Comment: I tried that, too. That solves the issue with the overlay's touch recognition, but it introduces a more serious problem with the video underneath not playing on its own due to the iOS prohibition of "autoplay."

Comment: Is this an iOS hybrid app or just a website? If it's an embedded UIWebView, you can override the autoplay prohibition in code - I can pull that up if you need it.

Comment: I think... if you put the <video> inside a <div>, then in the div, capture onClick, onMousedown, ontouchstart, and stopPropagation on the div, that might prevent the event from hitting the <video> element. Shot in the dark.